# MouseInputListener isn't working on a JButtons

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton

I have two `JButtons` that are extending two different inner classes of an outer class extending `JPanel`. I implemented `MouseInputListener` on the `JButtons` but it does not seem to be working. I tried placing the `MouseInputListener` on the outer class but it was not working either. I have a different class extending `JFrame` and also implementing `MouseInputListener` so I think it might be some overlay or hierarchy error but I'm not sure.

```
public class Frame extends JFrame implements MouseInputListener{
    static Dimension windowSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    static int windowWidth = (int) windowSize.getWidth();
    static int windowHeight = (int) windowSize.getHeight();
    TopBar design = new TopBar(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    public Frame(){
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            pack();
            setSize(windowSize);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
            setVisible(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setResizable(true);
            add(design);
            setState(java.awt.Frame.NORMAL);
            //setBackground(Color.decode("#449d9d"));
        }
    });
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }   
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { 
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {  
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { 
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { 
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(getWidth() + " " + getHeight());
        remove(design);
        windowWidth = getWidth();
        windowHeight = getHeight();
        design = new TopBar(windowWidth, windowHeight);
        add(design);
    }}
```

and

```
public class TopBar extends JPanel{
int windowWidth;
int windowHeight;
public class resourcesButton extends JButton implements MouseInputListener{
    public resourcesButton(int windowWidth, int windowHeight){
        setText("Resourses");
        setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        setBorder(new RoundedBorder(Color.decode("#f75280"),2,16,16));
        setBackground(Color.decode("#f75280"));
        setForeground(Color.decode("#0c120c"));
        setOpaque(true);
        setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        setBounds((int)(windowWidth/1.5), (int)(windowHeight/6.5)/2/3, (int)(windowWidth/8.33), (int)(9*(windowWidth/8.33)/16));
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Check");
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
}
public class startButton extends JButton implements MouseInputListener{
    public startButton(int windowWidth, int windowHeight){
        setText("Start Diagnosis");
        setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, windowHeight/45));
        setBorder(new RoundedBorder(Color.decode("#f75280"),2,16,16));
        setBackground(Color.decode("#f75280"));
        setForeground(Color.decode("#0c120c"));
        setOpaque(true);
        setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        setBounds((int)(windowWidth/1.25), (int)(windowHeight/6.5)/2/3, (int)(windowWidth/8.33), (int)(9*(windowWidth/8.33)/16));
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Check");
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
}
public TopBar(int windowWidth, int windowHeight){
    setLayout(null);
    this.windowWidth = windowWidth;
    this.windowHeight = windowHeight;
    add(new resourcesButton(windowWidth, windowHeight));
    add(new startButton(windowWidth, windowHeight));
}
@Override
protected void paintComponent (Graphics graphic){
    BufferedImage logo = null;
    try {
        logo = ImageIO.read(new File("SySLogo.png"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.paintComponent(graphic);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphic.create();
    g2d.setColor(Color.decode("#449d9d"));
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, windowWidth, (int)(windowHeight/6.5));
    try {
        g2d.drawImage(resizeImage(logo, (int)(windowWidth/8.33), (int)(windowHeight/8.6481)), windowWidth/16, (int)(windowHeight/48), this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        g2d.drawImage(logo, windowWidth/16, (int)(windowHeight/48), this);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    g2d.setColor(Color.decode("#f2eee3"));
    g2d.drawLine(0, (int)(windowHeight/6.5), windowWidth, (int)(windowHeight/6.5));
}
private BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int targetWidth, int targetHeight) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(targetWidth, targetHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D graphics2D = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    graphics2D.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight, null);
    graphics2D.dispose();
    return resizedImage;
}
```

}

Comment: why do you have this: addMouseMotionListener(this); ? Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: The last time I had to deal with mouse events manually, the interface had the name `MouseListener` and not `MouseInputListener`. Besides that, when you set a `Cursor` on a component, it’s the cursor to be used when the mouse is over the component anyway. So there’s no point in changing it on `mouseEntered`/`mouseExited` events. And why do you declare `throws IOException` for `resizeImage`  that can never throw this exception? Generally, this looks like an attempt to put as many anti-patterns into one code as possible.